# Reading exported variables in .env files nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

Im trying to get Environment Variables from a .env file.
They are saved as :

```
export KEY=VALUE
```

Reading it with dotenv returns undefined because of the 'export'

*I can't modify the .env*

is there a way to fix this issue without duplicating the .env file and saving it without the 'export'

Comment: Why can't you modify the .env file?

Comment: remove `export` from `export KEY=VALUE` and you will get key value using `process.env.KEY` after importing `require('dorenv/config')`